# opencv blobFromImage runs fine in main thread, hangs indefinitely in subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, opencv

I'm writing some code that will take an image, pass it through a neural network, then return the predictions and bounding boxes from the net back to the main thread. The end goal is to utilize multiple processes to do this. I've defined a 'detect' method as part of a "Detector" class. The method looks like this:

```
    def detect(self, image):

    self.debug("cnn_obj_detect:Detector:detect: Initiated")
    prediction = []

    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    self.debug("cnn_obj_detect:Detector:detect: Image dimensions calculated successfully {}".format((h, w)))

    # this is where it hangs in a subprocess
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)

    self.debug("cnn_obj_detect:Detector:detect: Blob loaded")
    self.net.setInput(blob)
    detections = self.net.forward()
    self.debug("cnn_obj_detect:Detector:detect: CNN successfully ran")

    for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        if confidence > self.confidence_min:
            self.debug("cnn_obj_detect:Detector:detect: Detected")
            idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])

            prediction.append([box, self.CLASSES[idx], confidence * 100])

    return prediction
```

When I call the methoed from the main thread, using no multiprocessing, it runs fine and I can print the results back out. I've been doing that like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    image = cv2.imread("example_02.jpg")
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    print(Detector("path/to/prototxt",
         "path/to/model", result_queue).detect(image))
```

However when I try to call the same method from a process, it hangs indefinitely at `cv2.dnn.blobFromImage`. If I do not use imshow before calling the detect method, it runs fine, even from within a Process. Is this a bug or am I missing something glaringly obvious? I'm using Python 3.6.2 on OSX and cv 3.3.0. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.